# GET Request Returning Empty Object in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've created a SpringBoot application that interacts with a react frontend UI. I wanted to ensure that data was getting passed in correctly through the API so I tried a GET Request in Postman. The response is returning an empty object instead of the data from the database, which I want. I can POST with no problem and compile with no errors. All files are in the same package. I have two rows in the table that correspond with the two open brackets, I'm just getting no data.

**Entity Class**

```
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "game_articles")
public class Articles {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "reviewer")
    private String reviewer;

    @Column(name = "review")
    private String review;

    @Column(name = "path")
    private String path;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "integer default 0")
    private int comments;

    public Articles(String title, String reviewer, String review, String path, int comments){
        this.title = title;
        this.reviewer = reviewer;
        this.review = review;
        this.path = path;
        this.comments = comments;
    }

}
```

**Controller**: Commented method was my first attempt.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ArticlesController {

    @Autowired
    ArticlesRepository articlesRepository;

    @GetMapping("/articles")
    public List<Articles> getAllArticles(){
//        createArticle();
        return articlesRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void createArticle(){ //ignore
    Articles a = new Articles(1L,"Title Test", "TyTest", "This is a test review", "path/totest", 10);
        articlesRepository.save(a);
    }


//    @GetMapping("/articles")
//    public ResponseEntity<List<Articles>> getAllArticles(){
//        try {
////            articlesRepository.findAll().forEach(articles::add);
//            return new ResponseEntity<>(articles, HttpStatus.OK);
//        }
//        catch (Exception e){
//            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
//        }
//    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface ArticlesRepository extends JpaRepository<Articles, Long> {
}
```

**SQL Query in the logs. I'm not sure why the columns are being referenced as articles0 but it had no effect on adding data to the database.**

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        articles0_.id as id1_0_,
        articles0_.comments as comments2_0_,
        articles0_.path as path3_0_,
        articles0_.review as review4_0_,
        articles0_.reviewer as reviewer5_0_,
        articles0_.title as title6_0_ 
    from
        game_articles articles0_
```

[image: Postman GET Request and Database Data.]

Comment: in my case it is because unauthorized with http code 401, after login the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to replicate your issue, as you are using lombok, I suggest you try using `@Data` in your `Articles` entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "game_articles")
public class Articles {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "reviewer")
    private String reviewer;

    @Column(name = "review")
    private String review;

    @Column(name = "path")
    private String path;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "integer default 0")
    private int comments;

}
```

It will generate all **`@Getter` and `@Setter`** methods for the entity, which you need for the entity when querying data from your repository, as well as `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, `@ToString` and `@EqualsAndHashCode`

Hope it can help you a bit.

Comment: Please carefully read this https://www.jpa-buddy.com/blog/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong/

Comment: Thanks, I added the getter and setter methods, and it worked. Also read the Article for @Data, I appreciate the wisdom!

Comment: I did but it doesn't work .. anyway, if I create getter and setter manually, it works.

Answer (score 2):

I added **@Getter** and **@Setter** in **Articles** entity, after it is working good.

Answer (score 0):

Just put in the body of your GET method the line

```java
return ResponseEntity.ok(articlesRepository.findAll());
```

Answer (score 0):

Lombok is not working i think.

Remove the lombok annotations and add all the things manually (getters, setters, all argument constructor and no argument constructor).

Comment: I put this up 'cause you're not wrong ... but I think we need to explain why it works for another people and not for us.